# How to for reset a child React component from a parent React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have a re-usable `<FormInput>` react component that's used to render `input` elements across a large web application.

It calls an `onChange()` handler after each change and passes the current `input.value` to it.

Here's a basic version of the component:

```js
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';

class FormInput extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    initialValue: PropTypes.string,
    name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  };

  static defaultProps = {
    initialValue: ''
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      inputValue: props.initialValue
    };
  }

  onChange(e) {
    // After setState completes, we call the `onChange` handler that was
    // passed by the parent, with the current input value as the only arg
    const afterSetState = () => {
      this.props.onChange(this.state.inputValue);
    }

    this.setState(
      { inputValue: e.currentTarget.value },
      afterSetState.bind(this)
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input
        onChange={this.onChange}
        value={this.state.inputValue}
        type='input'
        name={this.props.name}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default FormInput;
```

I have a parent component that calls this `<FormInput>` child component. I have a situation where **I want the parent component to be able to clear/reset the value on this `<FormInput>` child component**.

If I change the `initialValue` prop passed in to this component, it does nothing since that's only used "once" to set the initial value for the `state`. Perhaps if the whole component were forced to re-render, would it "reset" the whole component and accomplish this?

I'm struggling with this because as you can see, this component manages its own `state` with the current value. And I can't change this component to have it's value managed externally or by a parent, since it's used in numerous places in our application and is a shared component.

Is there an accepted way to accomplish this without inverting the responsibility of this component?

Thanks!

Comment: There is a super secret (not really) hack to do what you want - change the child’s “key” prop. It’s a common pattern used when a form’s initialValues change and you just want to “reset” all the state. React doesn’t actually “reset” anything, it just mounts a new instance with brand new state

Comment: If you want to reset it whenever the initial value changes, you’d just do this (in the parent) - `key={initialValue}`

Comment: What Adam said above it true (though on the latter suggestion you should only do that if `initialValue` is stable and not recreated on every render). However, you shouldn't use `key` as a solution to state architecture problems. That's not to say `key` is not the answer, just that you have to look at the bigger picture to decide. Without using `key`, you'd typically hoist the state of this form to the parent component that needs to reset it. You could also change the behaviour of `FormInput` to track changes in `initialValue` and when it changes, reset the state to that.

Comment: All that being said, in this specific example that you’ve posted, why can’t you just hold the value in state in the parent component? That’s the “react” way to do this. There’s lots of components that accept both initialValue and value as props, but they should only ever use one and never both at the same time. You could do the same here - if the parent passes initialValue, hold the state in the child, otherwise, if the parent passes value, then assume the parent holds the state, but the parent must pass an onChange as well

Comment: Ha jinx :D. Also just want to add the track changes in `initialValue` trick is something some libs do like Formik: https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#enablereinitialize-boolean.

Comment: Thank you both for your great explanation and suggestions! I like the approach of allowing both `value` and `initialValue`. If I pass `{ initialValue: null, value: 'foo'}`, how do I detect changes to the `value` prop? Is that was `componentWillReceiveProps()` should be used for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common way, if you're not writing a component library like antd/mui/etc, to create an input component is not to pass initialValue, but instead just pass `value` and `onChange`. The parent (or something higher) will hold the state and [control](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/textarea#controlling-a-text-area-with-a-state-variable) the input. Most often (not always, but most of the time), you don't need or want to hold state in the input itself, you just do this:

```
const MyParent = () => {
   const [value,setValue] = useState('')

   return <FormInput name="my field" value={value} onChange={setValue}/>
}
```

and then your form input would be:

```
const FormInput = ({value,onChange,name}) => {
    return (
      <input
        onChange={(e) => onChange(e.target.value)}
        value={value}
        type='input'
        name={name}
      />
    );
}
```

If you did want to support both an initialValue (uncontrolled component) and a value (controlled component), one way you could do it is like this:

```
const FormInput = React.forwardRef(({value,onChange,initialValue,name},ref) => {

    const [localValue,setLocalValue] = useState(initialValue)

    const handleOnChange = (newValue) => {
        onChange?.(newValue)
        setLocalValue(newValue)
    } 

    return (
      <input
        ref={ref}
        onChange={(e) => handleOnChange(e.target.value)}
        value={value || localValue}
        type='input'
        name={name}
      />
    );
})
```

Keep in mind, users (parents) of this component would pass **either**

1. both value and onChange props OR
2. just the initialValue prop (and probably a ref)

It's not common to pass an `initialValue` and an `onChange` prop because you don't **usually** want to be notified when the input changes (as the user types) - instead, you'd use a `ref` in the parent component to retrieve the value from the input when the user performs some other action.

Please keep in mind that there's no hard rules, what I've mentioned above are the most common cases. You can totally pass an `onChange` and an `initialValue`, but if you're going to be notified as the user types, you might as well hold the `value` in state, too.

The one hard rule that does exist is that you'd never pass both `value` and `initialValue` - that's non-sensical